# pass parameters to a user defined function called by xargs

Tags: bash

I have an array "foo". I want to pass the array to a self-defined function "bar" which is part of the xargs command. It takes me sometime to figure out how to invoke a user defined function in xargs. To achieve that, I export the function "bar" and use "bash -c" to execute it. However the $foo cannot be passed to bar(). $1 in bar() is empty.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks!!

```
foo="1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"

bar(){
   echo $1
   echo "asdf"
   sleep 2
}

export -f bar

echo $foo | xargs -n 1 -P 3 bash -c bar
```

Comment: `foo` is not an array, it is a string. See [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) for array use.

Comment: thank you for reminding me that, i tried both array and string so it was a little messy when i pasted the code

Comment: Hey, how did you solve it  ? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect a new shell started via `bash -c` to *not* have access to your function. I'd expect it to only be available to subshells started with `()` or `$()` or ``` `` ```.

If you want a newly started shell to have the function, perhaps store the function in a file and use `--rcfile foo` to load the function directly? Or, re-write it as a script file? (Since each execution of `bash -c` is already a new `fork()/exec()` pair, it might as well be to run your script directly.)